# How to use the AVFoundation to capture video data in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation

I've written the code below based on several examples I found online, in order to capture video data from the built-in camera on macOS. No fatal errors are thrown while setting up the `AVCaptureSession`, yet the delegate is not being called, and some apparent errors are logged as soon as I call `captureSession.startRunning()`.

So far, I've tried making small adjustments to my code (e.g. removing `videoSettings` on the output or the `sessionPreset` from the session), as well as checking in the systems preferences that my test app has camera access permission. However, the logs remain, and the delegate is not getting called.

***CameraInput class (includes delegate):***

```
final class CameraInput: NSObject {
    private lazy var sampleBufferDelegateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "CameraInput")
    private lazy var captureSession: AVCaptureSession = {
        let session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720

        let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)!
        let input = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
        session.addInput(input)

        let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        output.videoSettings = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
            kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey as String: true
        ]
        output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: self.sampleBufferDelegateQueue)
        session.addOutput(output)

        return session
    }()
}

extension CameraInput: CVInput {
    func start() {
        guard !self.captureSession.isRunning else {
            return
        }

        self.captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    func stop() {
        guard self.captureSession.isRunning else {
            return
        }

        self.captureSession.stopRunning()
    }
}

extension CameraInput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    private func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        // Handle captured frame
    }
}
```

***ViewController (default viewcontroller in new cocoa app):***

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    lazy var cameraInput = CameraInput()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.cameraInput.start()
    }
}
```

***The logged information:***

```
2019-01-02 16:27:15.821858+0100 TestApp[14182:1492243] [] CMIO_Unit_ScopeElement.h:200:SafeGetElement Throwing err: -67454
2019-01-02 16:27:15.823248+0100 TestApp[14182:1492243] [] CMIOUnitFigBaseObjectImpl.c:246:CMIOUnitCreateFromDescription Invalid paramater
2019-01-02 16:27:15.840190+0100 TestApp[14182:1492243] [] CMIO_Unit_Input_Device.cpp:244:GetPropertyInfo CMIOUInputFromProcs::GetPropertyInfo() failed for id 102, Error: -67456
```

Any help in getting this to work is greatly appreciated! Also, please inform me if more information is required.

**EDIT**
After running into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783312/how-to-access-mac-default-camera-using-swift-xcode), I've ruled out that it is a problem regarding sandboxing.

Comment: Do you call `startRunning()` on the capture session anywhere?

Comment: @NoHalfBits Yes I do. It's not included in this code, but I have a function `start()` in which I call `startRunning()` after creating the session. This is what causes the message to show up.

Comment: your code works if you enable Camera in Your Target > Capabilities > App Sandbox

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I did add it to the sandbox, but to no avail

Comment: Weird, here's my working version of your code: https://github.com/rfistman/video-capture-macos

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Strange that the code works when set up like that (it also works for me), but why would it stop working in a separate class?

Comment: Now that you've added more code I see what's wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the keyword `private` from your did `captureOutput:didOutput` method.

I guess it changes the signature enough for your method to not be called.

Comment: This was the problem! However, without the `private`, Xcode suggests to make it private which is the reason I did that in the first place. Making it explicitly `public` solves the warning, and makes it work

Comment: Mine didn't do that. There's something going on with your project, which is surely 
 more complicated than my toy example.

Comment: Well, at least the problem is solved. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be ok. Try to

- create a new "CocoaApp/Swift" project in Xcode
- paste both of your code snippets inside the AppDelegate
- add `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` to the app delegate declaration
- add `self.captureSession.startRunning()` to the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function of the AppDelegate
- enabling camera usage in the sandbox settings
- add a `NSCameraUsageDescription` to the Info.plist (macOS 10.14 and later)

I've just tested this, the delegate function *is* called repeatedly. 
I see the mentioned log output on macOS 10.14 / XCode 10 (it's not showing up on macOS 10.13 / Xcode 9), but it doesn't prevent capturing.

So the problem is not in the code given in the question. Make sure that all objects are actually created as intended, that the capture session setup runs, and that no objects - especially the output delegate - are released prematurely.

Comment: This works (using the code of @RhythmicFistman), which leaves me to wonder why it stops working when I put the code in a separate class. I've put a print in the `deinit` of `CameraInput`, but it's not called.

Comment: Weird - do you nil your lazy cameraInput?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact error. The marked answer helped me start down the right trail but I feel my problem is divergent enough to merit another answer

My code was this when it wasn't working.

`func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)`

That is what it used to be. I used Xcode autocomplete to get the current version of that.

`func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)`

So moral of the story... `Conversion to Swift <insert version> is Available` doesn't always work perfectly.

Comment: I wander if a radar is merited.